# Website Image as Title, Google Doesn't recognize Image

Tags: html, css, image

I currently have an image as my title for my website. Google is not recognizing this as the title and it shows up with something other than what i want in google search. I thought of perhaps adding the below h1 / link...

```
<a href="/">
<h1 style="postion:absolute;margin:-1000px -1000px;">my title</h1>
<img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="my title"/>
</a>
```

However this doesn't hide the title like I want it to. Any advice?

Comment: h1 isn't your title, <title> is your title. The <title> is what is used as the header for your website on Google search.

Comment: I know, its weird because I have the title I want yet when I search for the site, the second line of the site, a "welcome to this site" line following the home link (the image) is what is show as in google

Comment: Are you talking about the small excerpt that Google results display *beneath* the `<title>`? Is this where you're expecting the alt text to appear? You should edit your post and use the correct terms, "title" is not the same as "heading".

Answer (score 3):

The title that Google puts into its search result is not defined by the `<h1>`-tag but by the `<title>` tag within the the document's head.

So try this within the `<head></head>` tags:

```
<title>my title</title>
```

The `<h1>`-tag is picked up by Google but has nothing to do with what Google displays as your site's title, neither does the image.

That aside: for search engine optimization and accessibility reasons you should never use only an `<img>` as your header graphic.

If you want to define the text that Google puts under the search result's title, go for the meta description and put this in the documents head:

```
<meta name="description" content="The description of your site, as it will appear on Google Search." />
```

Comment: Additionally, Google doesn't use images, so even if the `<h1>` *was* what Google was picking up, it wouldn't use the image, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

h1 =/= title

You need a title tag in the head of your page. Also, I don't know if you can do this with an actual image or not (I really don't see why you would want to put an image as your title or what purpose it would serve). Maybe you're thinking of a favicon?

Also, theres no need to hide the title off of the page when you use a title tag. Since it's in your header it does not actually get displayed to the body.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
h1 { height:200px; background:url('logo.jpg'); width:300px }
h1 span { display:none }
```

HTML

```
<h1><span>My Title</span></h1>
```

And user1394965 is correct. `<title>` is going to drive what Google lists.